# java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format while reading from .CRT file

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa

I am trying to load the key from a .crt file. Below is my code

```
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
byte[] bytes;

try {
    bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);

    /* Generate public key. */
        X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = kf.generatePublic(ks);
```

Exception thrown @kf.generatePublic(ks).

Exception: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format

Below is the .crt file contents

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBpzCCAVECBEqbmP4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQAwXTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDjAMBgNVBAgTBVRF
//trimmed key
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I could not find what's wrong with my code. This key is used to RSA public encrypt a key (PBKDF2 key) in C code.

```
//openssl
RSA_public_encrypt(msgLen, msg, encryptedMsg, rsaPubKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)
```

I am trying to implement it in Java. Am I missing anything? Please guide

**UPDATE 1:**

Overcame the exception using the below code:

```
        InputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        inStream = RefundUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("refund.crt");

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
        PublicKey pubKey = cert.getPublicKey();

        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        byte[] cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(sessionKey);

        inStream.close();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Could you "untrim" the public certificate, then we can have a look what is in there and if there are any encoding mistakes or options that may not be present in Java. The Java runtime version would also be helpful.

Comment: It's a certificate, not a public key. You need to decode it as a certificate and then get the public key from that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Please see the update in the question. Would be helpful if you could check my code and see if it's correct. Here is what I am trying to achieve - [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232871/key-generation-and-encryption-using-pbkdf2-and-aes-256-in-java-rsa) Could you please check. I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: @user207421 Please see the Update in the question

Comment: I saw it. What I didn't see, and still don't see, was any explanation of what you had done wrong and how you had fixed it. So I supplied it.

Comment: Ok. The reason for this post was invalidKey exception which was thrown upon using the code in the initial post. I have pasted the code in the **Update 1** at the bottom of the question which helped to get over the exception. The main issue I'm working on is [this link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232871/key-generation-and-encryption-using-pbkdf2-and-aes-256-in-java-rsa). Would be helpful if you could review and share your thoughts

Comment: @user207421 I was able to do RSA encryption using the public key generated from the .crt file. Am I missing something? Did I do it right? Please guide

Comment: You don't have to explain it to me. You have to explain it to the entirety of SO, and you didn't. So I did. Explaining in comments doesn't count. And neither does asking a new question in another comment.